# "Принимать меры": правильно или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Словосочетание "принимать меры" сейчас употребляется повсеместно. Например: "Приняты меры по предотвращению лесных пожаров в летнее время".
Но я читала, что это выражение в корне безграмотное. Мне бы хотелось узнать мнение экспертов по этому поводу. И еще, почему выражение "принимать меры" считается неправильным? Почему меры нельзя принимать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принять/принимать меры

Разг. Предпринимать какие-л. действия для достижения чего-л. Ф 2, 91. /em> ***Калька с франц. prendre des mesures. БМС 1998, 372.***

Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007.

Иногда только калькированием можно объяснить возникновение в языке подобных выражений.

Comment: дословно это - принять шаги,меры, действия, а еще точнее размежевать. В основе это шаговые измерения.слово межа не из французского. Предпринять шаги, а проще  прикинуть, как решить проблему поэтапно, и соответственно действовать.Насчет межи можно глянуть у Фасмера, но это не этимология. Этимология идет от меда и стенок в  сотах, что и видно при сравнительном анализе, корневое слово мед.  межа--позднейшее заимствование в русском языке, вернувшееся с приходом католичества с запада.
Принять меру, это нормально, и поэтапно..

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютная корректность этого выражения иллюстрирует вторичный характер любых правил языка: никто не составлял этого выражения по правилам, но все им пользуются.
Видимо, кому-то пришло в голову, что если меры можно принять, то сначала кто-то должен их "передать". Вот и мучается зрящий "в корень".

Answer (score 0):

Подробнее об этом - здесь: [Принимать меры](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.49)