# Принять меры — фразеологизм?

Tags: фразеология

На уроке возник спор: является ли выражение "принять меры" фразеологизмом. Мне бы хотелось узнать мнение эксперта по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, это фразеологизм, зафиксированный в фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка.

> Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "принять меры", будучи калькой с одного из западноевропейских языков, является фразеологизмом, принципиально отличаясь от таких выражений, как "принять подарок" или "принять в организацию", где слово "принять" понимается буквально.

Comment: *Выражение "принять меры", будучи калькой с одного из западноевропейских языков* - вы, конечно, знаете с какого именно, но ни за что не скажете? Я вас разочарую. Подобные отсылки "в никуда" не слишком авторитетны. Я отчасти согласен, что разница между "принять подарок" и "принять меры" очевидна. Но причем тут калька с неизвестного науке европейского и почему это предопределяет фразеологичность выражения?

Comment: Почему же не скажу? Это калька с французского prendre des mesures. Французский известен науке и хорошо описан языковедами. В английском языке есть выражения take action (буквально "принимать действие"), take steps (буквально "принимать шаги") и take measures (калька с французского prendre des mesures), которое словарь определяет как take action to achieve a particular purpose. Например, "they took measures to improve performance".

Comment: Ну это уже лучше. Осталось понять, почему высчитаете именно так: что калька и что с французского.

Comment: А вообще http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.49 и вот http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41848  Французскую версию как-то все обошли стороной.

Comment: В смысле "обошли стороной"? Принять/принимать меры
Разг. Предпринимать какие-л. действия для достижения чего-л. Ф 2, 91.  Калька с франц. prendre des mesures. БМС 1998, 372.

Comment: Кто такой БМС? Большой медицинский словарь???))) Нет, я говорил о более или менее авторитетных источниках, на один из которых дал ссылку.

Comment: За источники спасибо. Как следует из этого источника, вкратце: принимать меры < брать меры (устар.) < prendre des mesures (фр.). Наличие в англ. аналогичного выражения, на что обратила внимание к.ф.н. Ольга Северская в своей статье, определяется тем, что английский подвергся влиянию французского.

Answer (score 1):

Если это спор на уроке, то и правда, лучше не вдаваться в детали и принять сторону словарей, пихающих во фразеологизмы все подряд. Школьному определению фразеологизма вполне соответствует.

Ну а если вдуматься, то "принять меры" - это "предпринять, провести мероприятия". По сути ничего идиоматического тут нету, и это сильно ставит под сомнение отнесение этого оборота к фразеологизмам с точки зрения академического подхода.

Answer (score 0):

Не причислял бы «принять меры» к фразеологизмам, т. к. здесь не больше премудрости, чем в «принять вправо» или «принять на грудь». Однако по классификации Мельчука «принять меры» можно назвать полуфраземой, а именно (по синтаксически главному слову) глагольной коллокацией типа: *оказать влияние, внести изменения*.

Comment: Ха-ха. Уж "принять на грудь"-то совершенно точно фразеологизм, даже чуть ли не идиома.

Comment: Существует два подхода к определению фразеологизма: широкий и узкий (традиционный). Согласно традиционному подходу к фразеологизмам относятся только словосочетания типа засучить рукава, спустя рукава, бить баклуши и т. д. При широком подходе к фразеологизмам относят все устойчивые словосочетания,например: Новый год, принять меры и т. д.

Comment: Или снять шляпу. Широкий подход расширится со временем, и тогда фразеологизмом (или полуфразом) станет «снять штаны». Меня это не устраивает. В моём ответе именно это — главное.

Answer (score -2):

Я думаю, что это калька с иностранного языка, это просто слепое преклонение перед всем западным. Типа, можно и не объяснять, понятно, мол, что там высшие существа, а мы так себе сирые, у них научились. Слово "МЕРА" - русского происхождения, а это словосочетание "принять меры" подразумевает установление каких-либо пределов действиям (установка мерок). И слово "принять" тоже русского происхождения и имеет значение "взять себе", только более глубокое. А попробуйте так же примитивно калькой с французского объяснить словосочетание "принимать пищу".

Comment: Вопрос-то был такой: фразеологизм или не фразеологизм?